# How can i start talking like native speakers

Tags: grammar

I speak the academic language well, but I want to speak the general language well so I have a question how to make a conversation in general and polite like a native speaker of the language

Comment: Hi Mead, that is an extremely broad question. If you're looking for resources, please try asking this at [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is no better method than by mixing with native speakers - if that's possible. Next best is to listen to popular radio/TV

Comment: The short answer is that you won't.  To speak like a native speaker you need to be a native speaker.  If you are more than four years old, your brain is probably too rigid.  But that doesn't matter.  You have the wrong goal.  You shouldn't try to "speak like a native" instead you should aim to be able to communicate effectively in every situation. And you do that by practice practice practice.

Comment: @JamesK - for Basque, people say two years old is too late. I did meet a German woman who spoke the most fluent Geordie (Newcastle) dialect I ever heard, and she came to England aged 18. This was 10 years later.

Comment: @JamesK, and then there are people like Richard Francis Burton, who "mastered at least five languages before turning 18 and added many more throughout his life." https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/63364/richard-francis-burton-englishman-who-went-mecca-and-east-africa It's a matter of brain plasticity and will power. Consider also Eliza Doolittle.

Comment: "mastering" doesn't mean becoming a native speaker.  Eliza Doolittle is a fictional character.

Comment: @JamesK Being a “native speaker” is not a black-and-white concept. Some people may be more attuned to language acquisition or demonstrate more talent for it than others, and research has shown possible genetic reasons as well. One child who learns a language at 7 may become native-level fluent, and another may never reach that level of fluency at that same age.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that this is actually a rather common issue in some English language learning circles, especially when required as an academic language for school. The key is to stop seeing English as academic jargon and start seeing it as a usable, communicative language. I have a few tips:

**1. Read more, preferably fiction.**
News articles, research papers, essays, etc. all tend to contain dense, abstract language that is not used on a day-to-day basis. In fact, I would recommend novels at a children’s or young adult level. This level of literature tends to use more practical, digestible language that will prove to be helpful for gaining a more intuitive sense for English grammar. Advanced literature tends to run the risk of using again, obsolete language.

**2. Expose yourself to native speakers.**
Obviously, the best way to do this is to practice speaking with native speakers. However, if this is not feasible or practical, try listening to and mimicking the speech of actors, singers, Youtubers, whoever you can find that speaks native English. You may use subtitles, especially in the beginning, but try to actively pay attention to how the language is being produced— the grammar, the tenses, the tone.

**3. Don’t try to break everything down into its grammatical or syntactical function.**
Again, English is a language used for communication. Native speakers do not try to parse everything that they’re saying or reading into their exact grammatical functions. Once you move past just trying to understand English and towards actively using it, it will start to flow better.